# when i try to run this code it collects first image and then camera turns off and frame is not responding

Tags: python, opencv

```
for label in labels:
    !mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages\\'+label}
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
    time.sleep(5)
    for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label, label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        cap.release()
```

error : OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

Comment: The image is not loaded correctly, there are errors in your path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The assertion you got hints that the image you passed to `imwrite` is empty. I suggest you put a breakpoint before `cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)` and make sure the image `frame` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem.
I fixed it by updating the correct id of video capturing device

```html
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

for me the video caputure device no. was 1